# Traversing the DOM to update the contents of a table

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to insert some dynamically generated html (via PHP) into a table, but I'm embarrassingly horrible at using JQuery functions to traverse the DOM.

Here's my table:

```
<table id = "tasks_table">
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Hours</th>
            <th>Task</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr id = "form">
            <form action="index.php" method="POST" id="task_form">
                <td><input type="text" id="deadline_text" name="deadline_text"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="duration_text" name="duration_text"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="description_text" name="description_text"/></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Add Task" id="task_submit"/></button></td>
            </form>
        </tr>

        <?php
            //TaskDB::generateTaskTable();
        ?>
        </table>
```

...And the code is going where the PHPcomment is--after the second row. I've tried using :nth-child and a few others without success. Any help would be much appreciated!

Jquery:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#task_submit').on('click', function(e){
                $.post('index.php', $("#task_form").serialize(), function(data){

                    $(' ').append(data);
                    console.log(data);
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Er... What is it you're trying to do, or change, or add?

Comment: Can you post your jQuery as well?

Comment: The problem *could* be that you're trying to get the children of the `tr`, which is actually the `form` and not the `td`s...

Comment: You know there's a .submit() jQuery bind for forms...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `after` or `insertAfter` methods, which are documented with examples [here](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/), e.g.

```
$(php_code).insertAfter('#form')
```

where `php_code` is the code you want to insert.

Comment: I didn't know about those functions! That worked, thanks a bunch! I'll accept the answer once I'm allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

Well, change `click` to `submit`. You can bind events to the submit event on a form.

And you're appending stuff nowhere:

```
$(' ').append(data);
```

Put a selector in there to append it to an actual element on the page.

**EDIT:** Oops, I get the question now. :P

Similar to Ghopper21's answer, you could do this as well:

```
$("#form").after( [html content to add] );
```